# is there a way to write the actual DOM to a string

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have an html document

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form>
<input type="text" value="" />
</form>
<input type="button" id="doit" value="do it"/>
    <!-- jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js">
        </script>            
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#doit").click(function(){
            var dom = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
            alert(dom);
            });
        });
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

if I edit the text field its value is still  the original blank value in the alert...WHY? and how do I see the actual DOM in a string?

Comment: what is documentElement?

Comment: @Jatin Dhoot: The root element. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.documentElement

Comment: `alert(document.documentElement.innerHTML);` works for me in FF & Chrome.

Comment: Please can you explain why you want to do this?

Comment: Have you tried accessing the `value` property of the `input` `Element`? (http://jsfiddle.net/z2CSM/)

Comment: @Michael: It doesn't for me. Mind you, he wants the textbox value to be reflected in the alert.

Comment: Do you want the value you've entered in the input field to be in the DOM??

Comment: @MatTheCat: Yeah I'm pretty sure he wants to be able to see changes to the 'value' field reflected in the DOM string. So, if he wrote in the input 'hello' he wants to see value="hello".. Don't think it's possible!

Comment: Text entered into an input box by the user is not part of the DOM. It's as simple as that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd need to set each attribute explicitly with the current value: http://jsfiddle.net/GW8eU/.

```
$("#doit").click(function(){
    $('*').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        for(var i = 0; i < this.attributes.length; i++) {
            try {
                var t = this.attributes[i];
                $this.attr(t.name, $this.prop(t.name));
            } catch(e) {}
        };
    });
    var dom = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
    alert(dom);
});
```

It's rather dirty and I do not see a real rationale behind outputting the DOM to a string, but it seems to answer your question.

One of the reasons it's dirty is that the `try` block is essential, because otherwise you'd be setting the `type` attribute of an `input` which is immutable. I'm pretty certain this won't work with other special attributes either, but for the `value` of an `input` it works fine.

Therefore I would still like to know what's the reason behind wanting the DOM as a string; probably there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: You really should ask the question of Why would you want to serialize the entire HTML state.

Comment: @Raynos: Because the OP's wish is my command. Well, I seriously don't see the reason either. It's just something that answers the question.

Comment: You should still warn the OP that his wish is silly / counter-productive ;) it's our job as web developers to warn others.

Comment: There is a legitimate problem I am try to solve here. In toying with this I am just trying to exercise a few ideas. using http://jquery.tiddlywiki.org/twFile.html I thought it might be possible to distribute a form that can save itself on a client machine. when the form is valid and the user is ready to submit I could use the native post action to send the data to our site. The reason for having the user edit their own form on their own machine is that we don't want to store draft forms. Also we know they all have browsers and the twFile method has a tiny footprint that is easy to distribute.

Comment: So I don't think the desire to achieve this is silly/counter-productive. it is probably just as easy to write a json blob into the document when I save it and do a jQuery.link to the edit fields but that starts to fatten up the document and I was trying to do the most lightweight thing I could.

Comment: thanks @pimvdb that does do it...like you say it may be silly in the greater scheme of things but it does seem to fix my immediate problem

Comment: ha! one of my colleagues just described what I'm doing as cool but unholy. Made my day.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you want to do this, the only reason I can think of is some kind of WYSIWYG editor that a user interacts with and then can get the HTML source from that? If that is the case then I don't think you are going to be able to achieve this.

If all you need is to get the value of the input field then rather than getting the whole pages HTML, you can get the value of the input by giving your input an ID:

```
<input type="text" value="" id="input_field" />
```

and using:

```
var value = document.getElementById("input_field").value;
```

Or in jQuery:

```
var value = $("#input_field").val();
```

Alternatively, if you want to be able to view the DOM as it is changed by javascript then I recommend [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) for Firefox, Developer Tools for [Chrome](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/overview.html)/[Safari](http://www.apple.com/safari/features.html#developer) or the [Developer Toolbar for IE](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18359). These will let you view the DOM as it is held in the browsers memory after modifications by javascript or the user.